# How do you compare a value from one dataframe to another in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two csv files for checking if we have processed an employee. The first is a list of the latest people hired. The second is the list of the people who have been processed after being hired. What I'm trying to do is check if a new hires ID is in the list of processed so I can verify if they need to be processed still.

Here is the test data from my first csv new hires.

```
id,fname,lname
15,Jack,Johnson
16,Brett,Smith
```

Here is the csv from the list of people that have been processed

```
id,fname,lname
15,Jack,Johnson
```

I want to be able to evaluate that "Brett" has not been processed and then add him to the df of processed people.

I have my dataframes here

```
df = pd.read_csv('newhires.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('processedhires.csv')
```

What is the best way to look for id 16 in the new hires csv and then add the entire row to the processed csv

Comment: This is giving me a syntax error SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: sorry missed the last bracket `df2.loc[~df2['id'].isin(df1['id'])]`